# AngularJS - ng:model - Field is readonly when bound to $q promise?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, angularjs, promise

I'm attempting to return a single record from a promise in AngularJs (1.0.7) and bind the result to a form. The form binds correctly, however the input fields are read-only - I cannot edit the values.

If instead I wrap the record in an Array and iterate using ng:repeat, the form binds correctly and I can edit values.

I've created a plnkr that demonstrates the issue clearly:

http://embed.plnkr.co/fOWyhVUfekRbKUSRf7ut/preview

You can edit the directly bound and list bound input fields, however the field bound to the single promise cannot be edited.

Is it possible to bind ng:model directly to an object returned from a promise, or do I need to use an array to get this to work?

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $q) {

  var person = {"name": "Bill Gates"}

  var deferList = $q.defer();
  var deferSingle = $q.defer();

  // Bind the person object directly to the scope. This is editable.
  $scope.direct = person;       

  // Bind a promise to the scope that will return a list of people. This is editable.
  $scope.list   = deferList.promise;

  // Bind ap romise to the scope that will return a single person record. This is *not* editable.
  $scope.single = deferSingle.promise;

  // Resolve the promises
  $timeout( function(){
    deferList.resolve( [person] );  // Array
    deferSingle.resolve( person );  // Just the record itself
  }, 100);


});


<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    Directly Bound - This field is editable
        <input ng:model="direct.name"/>
    <hr/>
    Singleton Promise - This field is *not* editable.
        <input ng:model="single.name"/>    
    <hr/>
    List Promise: - This field is editable
        <div ng:repeat="person in list">
            <input ng:model="person.name"/>  
        </div>

 </body>
```

**Edit**: After some debugging, I've found that the ng:model directive is *reading* from the value ('$$v') component of the promise, but writing directly to the promise object itself.

When attempting to edit the promise, the ViewModel keeps being reverted back to the original value, while storing characters on the promise itself. Thus if the user types 'asdf' into the input field, the result would be the following.

```
{Name: "Asdf", $$v: {Name: "Bill Gates"}}
```

Whereas we should instead be expecting

```
{$$v: {Name: "asdf"}}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this potentially a bug in AngularJS?

(To further clarify, the issue is the difference in behaviour between an Array and an Object returned by a promise. The direct binding is simply there as a control)

Comment: I found the issue and have created a pull request. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2854

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Seems that the issue has been introduced with AngularJS 1.0.3:
 http://jsfiddle.net/sonicsage/k8W4Y/6/

If you switch to AngularJS 1.0.2, it'll work.

There's an open issue on GitHub: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1827

The original thread on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/angular/I%2420think%2420this%2420may%2420be%2420a%2420bug%2420in%2420the%2420%2424parser%2420that%2420parses%2420the%2420original%2420user.name%2420on%2420a%2420Promise%2420object/angular/7qWlGBtRoP4/x8I0hT7IIZAJ).

There's also an interesting thread about automatic unwrapping here:
 https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1676

---

By debugging the application in the Chrome console, you can see that `single` is a function (the promise):

```
> $('body.ng-scope').data('$scope').single
Object {then: function, $$v: Object}
$$v: Object
then: function (b,g){var j=e(),h=
__proto__: Object
```

While `direct` is an object:

```
> $('body.ng-scope').data('$scope').direct
Object {name: "Bill Gates", $$hashKey: "004"}
```

However, pressing the keys on the read-only input has an effect on the `promise`, for example, selecting all the text and erasing it, although has no effect on the UI, has an effect on the property:

```
> $('body.ng-scope').data('$scope').single.name
""
```

You can further debug the app here: http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/rDo7bFZlBq4rRH2ZNJn1/

**EDIT**

IMO directly binding a promise to a field is not supported (is this officially documented?), changing the code as follows will work:

```
// Bind ap romise to the scope that will return a single person record. This is *not* editable.
  deferSingle.promise.then(function(data) {
      $scope.single = data;  
  }, function(data) {
      // error
  });
```

Here's the plunker: http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/rDo7bFZlBq4rRH2ZNJn1/

Comment: oops, I saw your edit after I posted my answer. I am not sure if it's an AngularJS bug.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not 100% sure about the binding thing being supported - however it works correct in almost all cases, and there's specific code in parse.js to handle unwrapping $$v.

Comment: Obviously the direct binding works, however the thing in particular to note is that the promise returning an 'Array' works, but the promise returning a Dictionary doesn't. The direct binding was simply added as a control.

Comment: James, there's an issue open on GitHub, find the link in the answer.

Comment: After a bit more investigation it appears that 1.0.2 is still not working as I would have expected - The field is editable, but it's still only binding to the root object, not $$v in the promise.

I'm guessing this is simply an unsupported feature.

Comment: I was still running into this issue with 1.1.5. Changing to 1.2 rc fixed the problem. $scope objects returned with a promise are completely editable as ngModels and will pass as form data correctly.

Comment: are you guys talking about TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'something' of #<Object> ?? Or i am somewhere else?